# Loop Through Array of Objects & Ignore Last Object

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm receiving json data in the form of an array of objects. At the moment, I have 6 objects, however, I want to ignore the 6th object. The code sample below effectively does this.

However, moving forward, the number of objects returned will fluctuate - it could be 1 or it could be 100. So, how do I modify this function to always drop the last object regardless of the # of objects in the array? Thanks!

```
var topCats = 'myobsfucatedurl?ACATHIER';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: topCats,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                if (i < 5) {
                    $('#footer-products').append($('<li>').html('<a href="' + item.MenuLink + '">' + item.MenuText + '</a>'));
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [**`for` loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!